# What would be correct join to use on the dataset?

Tags: join, left-join, relational-database, inner-join

I have two datasets:
First Data Set

```
     Date      Revenue  Country  Platform   Application
    2018-05-18   200       US     Google      XYZ
    2018-05-18   100       US      IOS        XYZ
    2018-05-18   200       AU     Google      XYZ
    2018-05-18   100       US     Amazon      XYZ
```

Second Data Set

```
  Date      Platform  Application  Country  ConversionRate
2018-05-18   Google       XYZ        US         0.56
2018-05-18   Amazon       XYZ        US         0.75
2018-05-18   Samsung      XYZ        US         0.26
2018-05-18     IOS        XYZ        US         0.45
```

I am trying to work out the appropriate join for the data. The main data is from First Data set. I want the conversion rate from the second dataset with all the data  from the first one and the value should be joined based on date as well as the application, platform, and country. I have tried inner join and left join but the output doen't seems right. Any help is appreciated.

The output that I am getting:

```
  Date      Revenue   Country   Platform  Application ConversionRate
2018-05-18    200        US      Google      XYZ           0.56
2018-05-18    200        US      Google      XYZ           0
2018-05-18    200        US      Google      XYZ           0
2018-05-18    200        US      Google      XYZ           0
```

the conversion rate should be same for a particular app(country, platform etc.) on a particular day. Even if the Google Platform is there multiple times, the conversion rate should repeat that number of times.

Comment: What output did you get and in what way did it deviate from your expectations ?

Comment: I am getting multiple columns with the same value. Some rows will have conversion rate as 0 but another column with the same info on same date has a conversion rate. I am using the Google Data Prep.

Comment: I meant "spell out the result set you got in the same way you spelled out the input".  (And pls do this by *editing* your question, not by commenting.)

Comment: @ Erwin Smout, I have added the kind of output that I am getting.

Comment: And what SQL produces that output ?

Comment: I am using Google Data Prep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. Just as we can add and condition in SQL, we can do that in Google DataPrep. That was the issue I was encountering. Simply added the multiple columns to check during the join operation and that seems to have solved the issue.